# Swagger UI from application/x-www-form-urlencoded to Appluication/json

Tags: json, swagger

I am using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` form.
Now my requirement is to shift it to `application/json`, but I am having issues.
I am attaching my json file of swagger.

```
        "/addToWishlist": {
            "post": {
                "tags": [
                    "Product Add To Wishlist"
                ],
                "summary": "Add product to user wishlist",
                "requestBody": {
                    "required": true,
                    "content": {
                        "application/x-www-form-urlencoded": {
                            "schema": {
                                "type": "object",
                                "properties": {
                                    "token": {
                                        "token": "string"
                                    },
                                    "id": {
                                        "id": "string"
                                    },
                                    "product_variant_id": {
                                        "product_variant_id": "string"
                                    }
                                }, "required": [
                                    "token",
                                    "id",
                                    "product_variant_id"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "OK"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

How to convert this form into application/json?

Comment: Have you considered mentioning what those issues are?

Comment: It just stops the execution of the json file.

Comment: Kindly help me out to convert this format into application/json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The issue is that you did not define the type of the parameters, respectively, defined them incorrectly.

Can you please try:

```json
"/addToWishlist": {
    "post": {
        "tags": [
            "Product Add To Wishlist"
        ],
        "summary": "Add product to user wishlist",
        "requestBody": {
            "required": true,
            "content": {
                "application/json": {
                    "schema": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "properties": {
                            "token": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "id": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "product_variant_id": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        }, "required": [
                            "token",
                            "id",
                            "product_variant_id"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "responses": {
            "200": {
                "description": "OK"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This solved my problem, but sincerely i didnt find any difference in my body also, can you please specify the difference. Thanks
Regards.

Comment: Sorry for the rather late reply, the issue was inside the `id` definition, you needed to specify `type` not `id`, the same issue in `product_variant_id`